# How can i store results of a query in an array?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to store last 5 employees_id's from employees table into an array.
I made the query correct and i have the array, but i can't understand the syntax to store the results in that array. Here's my code

```
    type tip_cod IS VARRAY(20) OF NUMBER;
    coduri tip_cod := tip_cod(6);
```

and here's my query

```
SELECT employee_id FROM (
SELECT employee_id from employees
where commission_pct IS NULL
order by salary asc)
WHERE ROWNUM < 6;
```

How can i store the results from the query in the array? As i need to update those values in another query. I know this can be done in a simpler way with subqueries but i'm doing it this way to better understand the concept of arrays in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Oracle then you can use a PL/SQL block:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE tip_cod IS VARRAY(20) OF NUMBER;
  coduri tip_cod;
BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO coduri
  FROM (
    SELECT employee_id
    from   employees
    where  commission_pct IS NULL
    order by salary asc
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM < 6;

  -- Do something with coduri
  FOR i IN 1 .. coduri.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(coduri(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c5da6a21c9a370299551178fcab1111)*

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. Now how can i use that information for a query? I want to update data for employees with the ids stored in `coduri`. I tried with DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE but it says `PL/SQL compiler error`

Comment: @DragosPolifronie If you want to ask something different to the question then its probably best to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [MRE] in that question with a detailed description of your tables, sample data and your expected output. You probably have an XY-problem and don't need to use an array and can do it all in a single SQL statement; but we can't determine that unless you completely describe what you are attempting to do.